# Why compilers generate a copy/move constructors when there is a templated constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

Mechanism for this is well explained here: [Template "copy constructor" does not prevent compiler-generated move constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832143/template-copy-constructor-does-not-prevent-compiler-generated-move-constructor), but I would like to better undestand why it is made this way. I understand that move constructor is not generated even if any other constructor is written by the programmer, because it is an indication that construction of object is non trivial and auto generated constructor will probably be wrong. Then why templated constructors that have the same signature as copy constructors are not simply named copy constructors?

Example:

```
class Person {
 public:
  template<typename T>
    Person(T&& t) : s(std::forward<T>(t)) {
      std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }

  Person(int n) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }

  // No need to declare copy/move constructors as compiler will do this implicitly
  // Templated constructor does not inhibit it.
  //Person(const Person&) = default;
  //Person(Person&&) = default;

 private:
  std::string s;
};
```

and then:

```
Person p("asd");        // OK!
//Person p4(p);         // error as Person(T&&) is a better match
```

if I make `p` const:

```
const Person p("asd");
Person p4(p);           // thats ok, generator constructor is a better match
```

but if I explicitly delete even a move constructor with:

```
Person(Person&&) = delete;
```

then auto generation of constructors is inhibited.

Comment: "*I understand that move constructor is not generated even if any other constructor is written by the programmer*" That's not true. Only the presence of copy constructors/assignment prevents the generation of move constructors.

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks, I looked up item 17 in Effective Modern C++, and also move construcor/assignment operator and destructor prevents generation of move constructor or assignment operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You understand wrong.

```
struct noisy {
  noisy() { std::cout << "ctor()\n"; }
  noisy(noisy&&) { std::cout << "ctor(&&)\n"; }
  noisy(noisy const&) { std::cout << "ctor(const&)\n"; }
  noisy& operator=(noisy&&) { std::cout << "asgn(&&)\n"; return *this; }
  noisy& operator=(noisy const&) { std::cout << "asgn(const&)\n"; return *this; }
};

struct test {
  noisy n;
  test(int x) { (void)x; }
};
```

`test` has generated move/copy construct/assignment.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fef25824692fa06b).

A copy/move construct/assignment written by a programmer results in the other ones being suppressed.

Now, writing a constructor suppresses the zero-argument constructor.  That may be why you are confused.

---

Templated constructors with the same signature as copy constructors are not copy constructors because the standard says so.

As it happens, templated code is rarely the correct code for a copy or move constructor/assignment.

The fact that forwarding references often grab `self&` and `self const&&` copy/move over the actual copy/move operations is a problem.  C++ isn't perfect.

Usually the way to avoid this is:

```
template<class T,
  class=std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, Person>::value
  >
>
Person(T&& t) : s(std::forward<T>(t)) {
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}
```

or `!std::is_base_of<Person, std::decay_t<T>>::value` which covers some other situations (like inheriting constructors).

Comment: thank you, I am reading now item 27 from Effective Modern C++ which deals with ways on how to avoid problems with universal (or now forwarding) reference constructors. Too bad Scott Meyers is not going deep into SFINAE.