# Why does my operator=(T&&) template only bind to a const& but not a &&?

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference, const-reference

When writing an overloaded function from an rvalue reference and a const reference, you might have code duplication, so I sometimes do both with the same code. As shown here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
  template <typename T>
  A& operator=(T&&) {
    if constexpr (::std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>) {
      ::std::cerr << "operator= move\n";
    } else {
      ::std::cerr << "operator= copy\n";
    }
    return *this;
  };
};
```

Now it is my understanding that this should implement both an `A& operator=(T const&)` and an `A& operator=(T&&)`. So given this code, in theory I would expect this invocation:

```
int main() {
  A a,b;
  a = b;
  a = ::std::move(b);
}
```

to produce the following output:

```
operator= copy
operator= move
```

However, to my surprise, the second line (!) is missing. How can I cover both at the same time?

---

I am compiling with g++ 8.3.0 and `-std=c++17`.

Comment: See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832143/template-copy-constructor-does-not-prevent-compiler-generated-move-constructor).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Oh, that's just bloody evil! Why in hell would they do this?! Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @bitmask I suspect because copy/move constructors and assignment operators have specific properties, and making some template instantiations "special" is a can of worms that nobody wants to open.

Answer (score 0):

Given the explanation pointed out by 1201ProgramAlarm, the interesting question is why it works for *either* situation.  The answer is simple: you assigned a non-`const` object, so `T` was deduced as `A&` (and `T&&` also becomes `A&`), producing a strictly **better** match than the implicit copy constructor that accepts `const A&`.  For the move constructor, or if you assigned a `const A`, the signatures are identical, and non-templates are **preferred** in that case.