# How works template constructors?

Tags: c++, types, constructor, copy-constructor

In some courses I discover some pieces of code with constructor that have types. Thing that i thought impossible with constructor.

More specifically i don't understand this two pieces of code :

```
template<class T>
class ValuePtr
{
public:
    template<class T> ValuePtr(ValuePtr<U> const &uPtr) :
        myPtr(uPtr.get()->clone())
    {}
    T* get() {return myPtr;}
    // ...
};
```

And this variation :

```
template<class T>
class ValuePtr
{
public:
    template<class U> ValuePtr(ValuePtr<U> const &uPtr) :
        myPtr(uPtr.get()->clone())
    {}
    T* get() {return myPtr;}
    // ...
};
```

What i see is a copy constructor, this I understand, but why is there a type before this type of constructor and why, in the second code, the type is different ? (template and not template) ?
What is the point of these constructor ?

Comment: `template<class T> ValuePtr(ValuePtr<U> const &uPtr)` can't compile.  Are you saying it does?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845896/why-doesnt-the-standard-consider-a-template-constructor-as-a-copy-constructor

Comment: `template<class U> ` is not a type. (And the copy constructor can't be a template.)

Comment: forget about the fact that it is a constructor for a moment (and the errors in the code you posted), then consider that class templates can have method templates. To instantiate them you instantiate the class with some template parameter, then instantiate the method with some other parameter

Comment: @NathanOliver : I am not very strong with Template, why the first bit of code can't compile ? Because it redeclare T ?

Comment: Yes, you redeclare `T`, which you can't do and there is no `U` in your code so `ValuePtr<U>` is a syntax error.

Comment: @molbdnilo Oups, i forgot that it must be writen template<class U> U myfunction to have the template U be applied to the function. So you're right, the function have no type here, i'm an idiot ^^ . Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver, there is a U, it's in the template : template<class U>

Comment: There is no `U` in you first code block of `template<class T> ValuePtr(ValuePtr<U> const &uPtr)`