# Template constructor selected over non-template overload

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have code similar to the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Base
{
    Base(int in) : _val(in) {}
    Base(Base &&b) = default;
    Base(Base const &b) = default;

    int _val;
};

struct Wrapper : public Base
{
    template <typename Type>
    Wrapper(Type &&val) : Base(std::move(val)) { _val++; std::cerr << "rval incr\n"; }
    template <typename Type>
    Wrapper(Type const &val) : Base(val) { _val++; std::cerr << "lval incr\n"; }
    Wrapper(Wrapper &&wrap) : Base(wrap._val) {std::cerr << "rval wrap\n"; }
    Wrapper(Wrapper const &wrap) : Base(wrap._val) {std::cerr << "lval wrap \n"; }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    int val = 10;
    Base b(val);
    std::cerr << (Wrapper(b)._val == 11 ? "fair" : "nope") << '\n';
    Wrapper w(20);
    std::cerr << (Wrapper(std::move(w))._val == 21 ? "fair" : "nope") << '\n';
    Wrapper w2(30);
    std::cerr << (Wrapper(w2)._val == 31 ? "fair" : "nope") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I ran it through godbolt (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rzs8xoWeE) and it confirmed what I was seeing in my development environment. I assumed initially this was a perhaps a compiler bug but it seems like all compilers agree on the following output:

```
rval incr
fair
rval incr
rval wrap
fair
rval incr
rval incr
nope
```

Why does it not call the `Wrapper` constructor overloads (resulting in 'rval wrap' in the second to last line of output)? In the context of functions as far as I understand it non-template overloads should be preferred over templated functions. Is that not true for this context or is there a different resolution taking precedence here?

Thanks.

Edit:
There was misunderstanding as to which constructor variants were viable:

> When you wrote: Wrapper(w2) note the argument w2 is an lvalue and so move ctor is not viable. You can confirm that this is indeed the case by changing it with Wrapper(std::move(w2)) and you'll get your expected output. Note i already did this in my second comment above and i also mentioned there that you'll get the expected output. The reason is also explained in the dupe. Please read the dupe.

Adding an overload with the signature `Wrapper(Wrapper &wrap)` solved my problem.

Comment: A ctor generated from a constructor template is never a copy/move ctor.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, in this line: `std::cerr << (Wrapper(w2)._val == 31 ? "fair" : "nope") << '\n';` would you not expect either `Wrapper(Wrapper const &wrap);` or ` Wrapper(Wrapper &&wrap)` as they both match?

Comment: This is explained in detail in the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72518781/why-isnt-this-templated-move-constructor-being-called) that i linked. I have explained there how the type of the parameters affect the output. The same thing applies here. To verify that this is indeed the case, you can change the last line in your given program to `std::cerr << (Wrapper(std::move(w2))._val == 31 ? "fair" : "nope") << '\n';` and you'll get your expected output. Note in the above statement the use of `std::move` that i have added.

Comment: No, your expectation is wrong. By writing `std::cerr << (Wrapper(w2)._val == 31 ? "fair" : "nope") << '\n';` the templated version should be called as expected. Note here the `Wrapper(Wrapper const &wrap);` is not preferred because the parameter is `const` and `Wrapper(Wrapper &&wrap)` isn't even viable because arguments should be rvalue here but `w2` is an lvalue.

Comment: Why is the templated version the expected one? The move ctor seems to be equally valid. Am I wrong in thinking that non-template overloads are preferred in overload resolution?

Comment: When you wrote: `Wrapper(w2)` note the argument `w2` is an lvalue and so move ctor is not viable. You can confirm that this is indeed the case by changing it with `Wrapper(std::move(w2))` and you'll get your expected output. Note i already did this in my second comment above and i also mentioned there that you'll get the expected output. The reason is also explained in the dupe. Please read the dupe.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I was unable to define a constructor with a signutare such as `Wrapper(Wrapper &wrap)` in my development context which I think is the one that I would want to add here. The issue I have is that in my context I am unable to define that constructor and also cannot enforce the `std::move` call since that is in the context of some STL function. I will see if I can more accurately reproduce the issue.
Edit: It seems that I am perfectly able to add that overload solving the issue. I must have made a mistake previously when I tried it.
Thank you so much!

Comment: In your program you're already using `std::move` in `std::cerr << (Wrapper(std::move(w))._val == 21 ? "fair" : "nope") << '\n';`. There also you're getting your expected output which is `rval wrap`. See [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SdmpZnuhtI)