# template constructor selected instead of copy constructor C++

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++17, language-lawyer

Let following program:

```
#include <variant>

struct A{
    A(){}
    ~A(){}
   A(const A&){}
   A& operator = (const A&) { return *this;}
   A(A&&){}
   A& operator = (A&& ) { return *this; }

   using var = std::variant<int, float>;

   var v;

   template<typename T>
   A(T&& t): v(std::forward<T>(t)){}

};

struct B
{
   A m_a;
   B( A a) : m_a(a) //calls template constructor instead of copy!
   {}
};
```

Live example: [godbold example](https://godbolt.org/z/sfEE5asov)

**Q: Why template generic constructor chosen instead of copy (or move) constructor?**

Edit : I think that, this is not duplicate of [Why isn't this templated move constructor being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72518781/why-isnt-this-templated-move-constructor-being-called)

Because that issue asks  `why templated constructor NOT called?`. That issue problem is  - NOT called templated constructor.

I'm asking `why templated constructor IS calling?`.
My problem is -- on the contrary, calling templated constructor.
:)

Comment: The example on Godbolt that's linked doesn't compile.

Comment: @FCo I think that's the point. The OP *think* it it should compile since there's a constructor that should be an (almost) perfect match to the argument. It's the compiler picking the "wrong" constructor that leads to the build error.

Comment: Try using `: m_a(std::move(a))` instead.

Comment: A **template** `&&` parameter is a forwarding reference (for both lvalue and rvalue), a non-template `&&` parameter is a move reference (an rvalue reference).  Same syntax — because that's the C++ way — but different semantics.

Comment: Dupe: [why template ctor used over move ctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72518781/why-isnt-this-templated-move-constructor-being-called)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a better match. The template will instantiate a ctor that looks like:
`A(T& t): v(t)){}`

either pass as const&
https://godbolt.org/z/78bdzczE5

or create better matching ctor
https://godbolt.org/z/b8WvjW38T

Comment: The question is why it's a better match.

Comment: It is better because the cv-qualifier matches exactly. That's the definition https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution. Read: Ranking of implicit conversion sequences (3e)